# Sublime Text, Omnisharp projects & workspaces and source control

Tags: version-control, sublimetext3, omnisharp

I have Sublime-Text 3 with Omnisharp running fine. I created a project to use with this, and now have the following two files:

- MySolution.sublime-project
- MySolution.sublime-workspace

Should these files be added to source control?

If not, what can I do to ignore the files in source control, but don't get clobbered on the equivalent of `git clean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Sublime Text docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) on projects:

> As a general rule, the sublime-project file would be checked into version control, while the sublime-workspace file would not.

Comment: The link you posted also has a version for 3. Identical text, though. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html